# How to make a search in 2 different collection (with pagination) in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections, one is `Users` and the other is `Posts`. I tried to `find()` in both collections and concat the result, but I faced a problem in pagination. My question is how can I achieve this in one query so I can paginate.

Example:

```json
Users:

    {
        _id: 1
        username: 'test',
        type: 'users'
        ...
    }
```

Posts:

```json
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'test3',
      type: 'posts',
      ...
    }
```

And when I search for example 'test' I should get both user data and post data with 'test' in the username/name.

Also, I tried aggregate but there is nothing common in the two tables to join.
And I have a question, will these cause performance issues for many searches ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you share your sample dataset and expected output so that we can see what we can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/) aggregation stage. It performs a union of two collections.

- `$unionWith` to perform union of two collections. Note that `$unionWith` is available starting with MongoDB version 4.2.
- `$match` with `$regex` to filter only documents where **username** or **name** field contains a specified string. Note that `$options: "i"` will make the search case-insensitive. If you want case-sensitive search, just remove `$options: "i"` from the query.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$unionWith": "posts"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "username": {
            "$regex": "test",
            "$options": "i"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": {
            "$regex": "test",
            "$options": "i"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QTKPq3ldX-U)

Comment: thank you, I just have one more question, In my real DB in my users collections the name is actually `username`, so how the query will become ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it?